# Importing Django App functions in celery.py

Tags: python, linux, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am developing an application where i have to periodically call a function which is in myapp/task.py from the celery.py file which is located in my project directory.But when I do an import statement from the celery.py file like

```
from myapp.tasks import test
```

I get the following error which I am not able to resolve:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Here is the code from init.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

 __all__ = ['celery_app']
```

The Code from celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import,unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from myapp.tasks import test
```

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','project.settings')
  app=Celery('project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings',namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.on_after_configure.connect

def setup_monitor_call(sender,**kwargs):

```
   sender.add_periodic_task(30.0,test.s(),name='call test every 30 seconds')
```

Now in my app directory there is a file named tasks.py which has the test method which i am calling from celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery.decorators import task
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger=get_task_logger(__name__)

def test():
  print("Hello Celery")
```

Now the exact problem is that when i write the following import statement in the celery.py file:

```
from myapp.tasks import test
```

and then when i run python manage.py runserver i get the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

The moment i remove the import statement, the server runs correctly. I cannot figure out why?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing at least some of the code in both modules.

Comment: I have now added the source code

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to an incompatibility with that import, for example a cyclic import. I have recently worked on a project with celery and sometimes imports are as fragile as a house of cards.
I recommend that you make the calls to the tasks as follows in this example:

```
.....otherimports
from celery import Celery

import incidencias.celery_conf as celery_conf

app = Celery('myname')
app.config_from_object(celery_conf, namespace='CELERY')
app.conf.timezone = 'Europe/Madrid'

def some_def():
     code code code code....  
     app.send_task('myapp.tasks.test', args=[whatyouneed.ifneed])
```